# Delete query working in PgAdmin 3 but not working on Java JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a list of times saved in a database where the date (end_time - timestamp) is bigger that my reference day for a specific employee (employeeId - integer).
The query works perfectly on pgAdmin III. However I cannot make it work in JDBC.
It works, but it deletes everything from that particular employee and not just the dates I want. I looks like it ignores the date in the Where clause. Also, I do not get any exception. 
The variable nextDayTimestamp comes out like: '2017-03-31 12:00:00.0' 
Could anybody please help?

```
 public void deleteBigListOfPeriodOfWorkFutureOnly(int employeeId, LocalDate referenceDate) {
        Connection myConn = null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt = null;

        try {

            myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

            LocalDate nextDay = referenceDate.plusDays(1);
            Timestamp nextDayTimestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.of(nextDay, LocalTime.NOON));
            String sql = "delete from working_time where working_time.end_time > ? and employee_id = ?";

            myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

            myStmt.setTimestamp(1, nextDayTimestamp);
            myStmt.setInt(2, employeeId);

            myStmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            CloseConnection.close(myConn, myStmt, null);
        }


    }
}
```

[image: sample of working_time table]

Comment: What is `end_time` in your database, a timestamp or a datetime?

Comment: I guess the first condition is always true, just like @GuillaumeF.said, it might be having something to do with type.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. end_time is timestamp without time zone.

Comment: @JunbangHuang I also tried Date instead of Timestamp for my variable. In my case, the first condition in the where is the date condition and it looks like it is ignored. Just the second condition "employee_id = ? " is recognized. I also tried to swap them before, and also did not work. Is there another way that I could do this query?

Comment: @evzpav can you try changing this "working_time.end_time" to "end_time"?

Comment: @JunbangHuang Thanks for the reply! I had tried that already before. I also tried changing executeUpdate() for execute(), I also update the postgres jar file, I also tried changing my variable to Date instead of Timestamp. I do not get any errors, no exceptions. It is just that the where clause for the date is ignored somehow.

Comment: @evzpav can you share your the schemas?

Comment: @JunbangHuang please see above the image in the question description.

Comment: @evzpav I tried your code. It should work. Is reference day correct? Sorry have to suspect everything. Can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: @JunbangHuang the referenceDate comes as LocalDate: "2017-03-31". I checked that with IntelliJ's debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer! I made a mistake calling "delete from employee where employeeId=?" from another method that I was not taking notice. It was at a higher level. That is why it was deleting every employee.
I just removed that method and THE CODE MENTIONED IN MY QUESTION ABOVE DO WORKS!
Thanks a lot for the effort and time trying to help me! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

I think First where condition is always true you should:

First: print the nextDayTimestamp and make sure it is valid

Second: If it is valid try the condition on postgresql sql query

Comment: The nextDayTimestamp is like '2017-03-31 12:00:00.0'. I used it concatenating as string just to check if it would work, but I got the same result. It deletes everything from database for that employee, ignoring the date.

Comment: Try to cast 2 variables to the same type like date without timestamp and try again

Answer (score 1):

If the Connection coming out of that dataSource doesn't have AutoCommit turned on, your update will succeed, but the "transaction" never commits, so in the database won't reflect your changes.  Maybe put an explicit `myConn.commit();` after that executeUpdate and see if your updates now show up in the database.

Comment: I tried that myConn.commit() after the executeUpdate but I got an error that the AutoCommit was on.